# ROLE_USER and ADMIN access restriction to URL's

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have

> /welcome/employees - Employee List
>
> /welcome/employees/edit/ - Edit Employee
>
> /welcome/employees/find/ - Find Employee

I want to define `ADMIN` to access everything, but `USER` just to View List and find.

How should I configure accordingly.

```
   @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/welcome", "/welcome/employees", "/welcome/employee/find").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .antMatchers("/welcome/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout"); 
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify ROLE to access every authenticated user can access that url. You can try like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/welcome/employees/edit/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
    // part of your config
}
```

If  `USER` try to access `/welcome/employees/edit/` will get 403 error. But `ADMIN` can access every url with this config. Because if you don't specify role for access everyone can access that url. But except `edit` page every user can access `every url` if logged in. Don't forget this.

Comment: I actually see this in between The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try:
Reloading the page
Clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and it doesn't seem to start now, please help

Comment: I added this .permitAll() and too many redirects solved. and it now seemsthat user is restricted to edit page with your version of code, what if I also wanto restrict hime to /add?

Comment: You can add `/add` to `antMatchers()` and now only admin can access `/add`.